# Jquery-templ and keys with a hyphen (-)

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json array with the key 'BASIS-TYPE'. If I use this value in the markup:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/jquery-plugins/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var jsonarray = {"_id":"15", "BASIS-TYPE":"80"}
        var markup = "<tr><td>${_id}</td><td>${BASIS-TYPE}</td></tr>";
        $.template( "tableTemplate", markup);
        $("#templtable").replaceWith('<table id="templtable">'+headers+'</table>');
        $.tmpl( "tableTemplate", jsonarray ).appendTo("#templtable");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    Tabel:</br>
    <table id="templtable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

it will look for '`BASIS`' and not '`BASIS-TYPE`', throwing the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: BASIS is not defined
```

Replacing BASIS-TYPE will show the required results.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: FYI I checked and `"BASIS-TYPE"` is definitely a valid object property name.

Comment: it is surely, but the problem occurs when you need to access it, you will need to try something like for( prop in obj )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change to the template will solve your problem:

```
var markup = "<tr><td>${_id}</td><td>${$data['BASIS-TYPE']}</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you will have to rename your property,

one solution is this:

loop over the array

```
for (var x in jsonarray ) {
   if( x == 'BASIS-TYPE' ) { jsonarray.basisType = x; break; }
}
```

and then in the template engine use:

```
var markup = "<tr><td>${_id}</td><td>${basisType}</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The only thing is that I don't know the names of the keys in advance, because in my application the name of the key will be variable.

Comment: then how do you put that in your template?

Comment: I manage to implement a rebuild that removes the - from the variable name. So it will do things automatically. The only thing is that ${basisType} contains the value "BASIS-TYPE" and not 80 as expected